# What is the difference between the ByteBuf retrieved from Context versus any other ByteBuf

Tags: netty, netty4

I found out that using `ByteBuf` derived from `ChannelHandlerContext` behaves exactly the same as when using `ByteBuf` created via `Unpooled` for example.

That is, both of these two works:

```
ctx.write(ctx.alloc().buffer().writeBytes("Hello World".getBytes()))
ctx.write(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("Hello World".getBytes()))
```

Is there any difference in the behaviour when `ByteBuf` retrieved from `ctx.alloc().buffer()` is used versus any other means of creating a `BytBuf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChannelHandlerContext` uses the `ByteBufAllocator` that is configured for the `Channel`. Which is by default using the `PooledByteBufAllocator` which means buffers are pooled for performance reasons.